# HIde form elements when page initially loads

Tags: javascript

HI I have a drop down menu, which determins which sections of a form should be displayed.  This works, except for when the initial page loads all of the elements are shown.  Once you make a selection it then displays only the correct elements.

Below is my Javascript, is there a way to set all of the elements to hidden initially, sorry if this is a stupid question but i am new to javascript.

```
if (current_value == "page_name") {
    document.getElementById("contains").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("term").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("countries").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("postcodes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("repeater").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("visitor_type").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("page_visits").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pvisits_value").style.display = "none";
}

else if (current_value == "postcode") {
    document.getElementById("contains").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("term").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("countries").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("postcodes").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("repeater").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("visitor_type").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("page_visits").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("pvisits_value").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this code is in dire need of an object (hash) associating `display` values with element ids.

Comment: do it without if condition, if you have no current value set initially. So when page loads, the code will execute once.

Comment: Add display='none' to all the elements in css or inline style whom you dont want to appear when page is loaded initially

Comment: Tried that, but when the elements are then selected they don't show either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give class attribute to all element.

Eg: if you have a input element like

```
<input type="text" name="something" id="something" class="hideme" />
```

hide element by using same class name for all elements as I explained above

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hideme").hide();
});
```

Comment: are you using jquery ?

Comment: I have some Jquery in the page yes?, so maybe it's a conflict ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that?